# Safety in console clearing (Java)

Tags: java, console

In languages such as C and C++, I hear that use of `system("cls")` and equivalents are "unsafe" or ugly.
Do commands such as `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");` carry the same opinion?

I am looking for a safe, reliable way of clearing the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking for a safe, reliable way of clearing the console.

There is none.  There is no method that is guaranteed to work in all situations.

For example, consider the case where the console is a teleprinter of some kind.  (I'm serious ...)  Or a virtual console that logs absolutely everything.

The reality is that there is sufficient diversity in the behaviour of console "devices" that there is no solution that will work all of the time.

Running one of the clear screen utilities is as good as you are likely to get.  But it is not guaranteed to always work.

---

BTW, this is not a language specific, or even OS specific issue.  In some cases, it goes back to the actual hardware that you use for your "communications".

Answer (score 0):

Old school:

```
for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {
  System.out.println();
}
```

May not work on really big monitors.